# ¿Cómo conecto y pruebo mi aplicación Java con cassandra?

Tags: jdbc, cassandra

Generalmente en los motores de datos se pude probar la conexión haciendo uso de una consulta, por ejemplo en Postgresql puede ser `select 1` la idea es hacer esto mismo para cassandra.

Answer (score 0):

Para realizar esta prueba se agregaron las siguientes dependencias de Maven:

```
<dependencies>        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--test-->         
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Se creó la siguiente prueba que consulta una fecha.

```
 @Test
public void obtieneLaReferenciaAlCluster(){
    String puntosContacto[]={"localhost"};
    int puerto=9042;
    String sentenciaVerificacion="SELECT toDate(now()) FROM system.local";
    Cluster cassandrac=SingletonCCluster.getCluster(puntosContacto,puerto);
    Session session = cassandrac.connect();        
    ResultSet rs = session.execute(sentenciaVerificacion);               
    Row one = rs.one();
    LocalDate date = one.getDate(0);        
    GregorianCalendar gc=new GregorianCalendar();
    String anio_esperado=""+gc.get(Calendar.YEAR);        
    String resultado=""+date.getYear();
    Assertions.assertThat(resultado).startsWith(anio_esperado);
}
```

El código "completo" puede consultarse en [github](https://github.com/tutmosisII/CRUDBasicoCassandra) en la rama test1